# GNU Parallel - grepping n lines for m regular expressions

Tags: grep, large-files, gnu-parallel

The GNU parallel [grepping n lines for m regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions) example states the following:

> If the CPU is the limiting factor parallelization should be done on
>   the regexps:
>
> ```
> cat regexp.txt | parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f - bigfile
> ```
>
> This will start one grep per CPU and read bigfile one time per CPU,
>   but as that is done in parallel, all reads except the first will be
>   cached in RAM

So in this instance GNU `parallel` round robins regular expressions from `regex.txt` over parallel grep instances with each `grep` instance reading `bigfile` separately. And as the documentation states above, disk caching probably ensures that `bigfile` is read from disk only once.

My question is this - the approach above appears to be seen as better performance-wise than another that involves having GNU `parallel` round robin records from `bigfile`over parallel `grep` instances that each read `regexp.txt`, something like

```
cat bigfile |  parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f regexp.txt -
```

Why would that be? As I see it assuming disk caching in play, `bigfile` and `regexp.txt` would each be read from disk once in either case. The one major difference that I can think of is that the second approach involves significantly more data being passed through pipes.

Comment: In any case, that's not functionally equivalent if some lines may match several regexps.

Comment: A point in favor of the first command is that you could add the `-n` option to `grep` and get line numbers in `bigfile`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, true enough. If anything, approach 2 is closer to the stock `grep -f regexp.txt bigfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to GNU Parallel --pipe being slow.

```
cat bigfile |  parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f regexp.txt -
```

maxes out at around 100 MB/s.

In the man page example you will also find:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile grep -f regexp.txt
```

which does close to the same, but maxes out at 20 GB/s on a 64 core system.

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile -k grep -f regexp.txt
```

should give exactly the same result as `grep -f regexp.txt bigfile`